# Setting dimensions of an iframe AFTER content has loaded

Tags: jquery, events, iframe

I'm using an iframe to display content. After the iframe loads and event fires to set the height of the iframe because it is unknown ahead of time how tall it will be. Unfortunately this doesn't always work. I assume it's because the load event fires before the content loads in the iframe. Is there a way, in jQuery, to make this work properly. Here's the code:

```
function UpdateIFrameSize(iframeSelector) { 
    try {
            $(iframeSelector).load(function () {
            $(iframeSelector).width('98%');
            var height = parseInt($(iframeSelector).contents().find('body').attr('scrollHeight'));
            $(iframeSelector).height(height + "px");
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it dosn't always work"? Do you get an exception? Is the wrong size used?

Comment: no exceptions, just sometimes doesn't work. I know it sounds weird..but.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're loading a HTML page inside the iFrame, why not simply add the jQuery `$(document).ready()` function to the page inside the iFrame, and have it update the height using a delegate in the parent window?

For example, in the iFrame:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theHeight = $(window).height();
    window.parent.setiFrameHeight(theHeight);
})
```

Comment: While this didn't completely solve my problem, it did send me down the correct path. http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing

Thanks! Accepted.